# Can anyone please list important books on Buddhism?

Tags: texts, buddha, books, dhammapada

What all are the important books, that are part of Buddhism, other than Dhammapada?

Comment: See also [List of book recommendations](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25889/254)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on which Buddhist school or tradition you are referring to.

For the Theravada school, the main scripture is the [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81li_Canon) or the [Tipitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka), in the Pali language. Tipitaka means the three baskets. The three are the Sutta Pitaka which is the basket on the teachings of the Buddha and his disciples, the Vinaya Pitaka which is the basket on the monastic rules, and the Abhidhamma Pitaka which is the basket of philosophical analysis.

Here's one view of it below. The Dhammapada is only one book of the 15 books of the Khuddaka Nikaya, which is part of the Sutta Pitaka.

You can find it online at [AccessToInsight](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/index.html) or [SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/).

There are also the commentaries to the Tipitaka and other supplementary writings, such as the Visuddhimagga.

Also see [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/471), [Recommendation for Suttas](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/31032/471) and [How to Study the Suttas?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8462/471).

Other Buddhist scripture for Mahayana Buddhism are either in [Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit_Buddhist_literature), [Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Buddhist_canon) or [Tibetan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Buddhist_canon). The Vajrayana school is part of Mahayana.

[image]

Comment: What is the main difference in Mahayana and Theravada Buddhism? I have understood that Mahayana is based on Shunyata and Madyamaka(middle path)

Comment: @ManuKumar There is [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/67/471) but I think you can also ask another question here at Buddhism.SE.