# Was Buddha had a expected food poisoning?

Tags: the-buddha, buddha

Refer to the link below, the Buddha was poisoned in his last meal. Where can i find more information about this?

[Why was Buddha poisoned?](https://www.quora.com/?pa_story=MjEyNTU1OTIxMzM2OTY2MDQwfDIxMTEwNjIzNTc2MzU5MHww)

> The Buddha died after eating a meal often called “pig’s delight” (Skt.
> sukaramaddava, lit. “soft” or “mild pig”) offered to him by the
> metalworker, Cunda Kammāraputta, in his mango grove in Pava, between
> November and January, en route to Kapilavastu, the place of his birth.
> The nature of this meal is uncertain. It might have been pork (the
> Buddha was not vegetarian) or mushrooms

There are [many version](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Buddha-poisoned) of the cause of death. Which one found to be truth and supporting facts?

Comment: I was also told by my Buddhist friend that he died because of eating pork. It seems pork was a poison then ... these days pork is a delicacy... or may be death as event is a coming together of various factors including beliefs of people who lived then... may be pork was an abomination for upper caste hindus.. Metal worker did not give him food in good spirits,... may be there was hatred.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in the [Mahaparinibbana Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html#cunda)'s story about the meal containing *sukara-maddava* served by Cunda to the Buddha, which is presumed to be the cause of dysentery experienced by the Buddha.

The Mahaparinibbana Sutta is sutta 16 of the [Digha Nikaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABgha_Nik%C4%81ya) of the [Sutta Pitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutta_Pi%E1%B9%ADaka) of the [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81li_Canon), which is the sutta explaining the events leading to the Buddha's passing away and events that occurred after that.

The [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81li_Canon) is the authoritative canonical scripture of [Theravada Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theravada), and is an [Early Buddhist Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Buddhist_texts). Please read [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/33803/471) for details.

In [this footnote](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html#fn-38), *sukara-maddava* is explained:

> *Sukara-maddava*: a controversial term which has therefore been left
> untranslated. *Sukara* = pig; *maddava* = soft, tender, delicate. Hence
> two alternative renderings of the compound are possible: (1) the
> tender parts of a pig or boar; (2) what is enjoyed by pigs and boars.
> In the latter meaning, the term has been thought to refer to a
> mushroom or truffle, or a yam or tuber. K.E. Neumann, in the preface
> to his German translation of the Majjhima Nikaya, quotes from an
> Indian compendium of medicinal plants, the Rajanigantu, several plants
> beginning with *sukara*.
>
> The commentary to our text gives three alternative explanations: (1)
> the flesh from a single first-born (wild) pig, neither too young nor
> too old, which had come to hand naturally, i.e., without intentional
> killing; (2) a preparation of soft boiled rice cooked with the five
> cow-products; (3) a kind of alchemistic elixir (*rasayanavidhi*).
> Dhammapala, in his commentary to Udana VIII.5, gives, in addition,
> young bamboo shoots trampled by pigs (*sukarehi maddita-vamsakaliro*).